# OAuth Client Java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, client

Could someone point me in the right direction on creating an OAuth2 Client in a java? Are there some tutorials that are easy to understand, or potentially websites that go through the process of creating such a client? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at Apache Oltu.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/OAuth+2.0+Client+Quickstart

Comment: Thanks looks like what I am looking for!